# submit form with normal link, wont work

Tags: html

I have this:

```
<a style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold;"
   href="javascript:submit()">Search</a>
```

As instead of a button with submit, but nothing happens when you click..

How can do this?

Comment: What does your `submit()` function look like? It is not the submit function of the form, if you think this. You have to reference the form explicitly, e.g. `document.formname.submit()`.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `<input type="submit">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `document.yourFormNameHere.submit();` not just `submit()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id='demoForm'><br>
Demo field<input type='text' name='demoItem' /><br>
</form>

//place this link anywhere in html
<a style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold;"
   href="submitForm()">Search</a>

///java script
function submitForm()
{
    document.getElementById('demoForm').submit();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the form to be submitted..

so give the form an id and use it to target the form like this

```
<form id="someid">
...
<a style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold;" href="javascript:document.getElementById('someid').submit()"  >Search </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have javascript:submit(), but what is it going to submit? Try something along the lines of :

```
href="javascript:document.getElementById('formId').submit();"
```

Or even better yet, try giving an id to your  and then move the styles and javascript into separate files appropriately. This will keep your markup clean and more manageable.

```
/* in some sort of external css that is included */
#formSubmissionLink {
    display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
}

/* in some sort of external JS that is included at the end of the html*/
(function () {
    document.getElementById("formSubmissionLink").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("formId").submit();
        return false;
    };
})();
```

and then your html would be:
    <a id="formSubmissionLink" href="#">Search</a>